# dialogref.afterclosed() result is empty Angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

I want to pass data from my dialog to the parent component but I got result empty.
Here my dialog template:

```html
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
      <input [(ngModel)]="data.animalData" matInput placeholder="Favorite food" value="Sushi">
</mat-form-field>
```

Here my parent component ts :

```js
export interface DialogData {
  aze:any;
}

openDialog(az:any) {
  let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(MyDialogComponent, {
    width: '100px',
    data: {aze:this.az}
  });
  dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
    this.azz = result;
  })
}
```

I want to pass data.animalData to result but I got it empty.

> Notice that : `console.log(this.data.animalData);` is not empty in the dialog component.

Comment: Post the code where you close the dialog.

Comment: just with a button (  <button mat-raised-button mat-dialog-close type="button" class="Discard-btn">Cancel</button>  )

Comment: You need to use the `close` function to close your dialog and pass the result to it, such as `this.dialogRef.close(resultData)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just add the returning value to your button's mat-dialog-close attribute like this:

```
<button mat-raised-button [mat-dialog-close]="data.animalData" type="button" class="Discard-btn">
    Cancel
</button>
```